# Текст переходит на другую сторону

Tags: html, css

Можно ли как-нибудь зафиксировать текст, чтобы он не перемещался при сжатии
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Происходит что-то такого рода
Html

```
<div class="container-fluid banner">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-md">
                    <div class="navbar-brand"></div>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <!-- <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTAC</a>
                        </li> -->
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 info">
                <p class="text-center">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-md text-center">Начать учиться!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Css

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:#fff;
    font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
 
}
.banner{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background:url(https://psv4.userapi.com/c237131/u369910502/docs/d34/031df9f321b4/main2.png?extra=ZtioU9nvleIKIWi6QiK6WOHJot5PSXiv2XPHQqQc0DOmBwgpajTNDfbS0l4JwzacyMGac_Lx_wQib2Cu-Mjt91Lqyy6gcs-Y1yMMhIGhgJ3fgkKUUjHAm9PzrzNPxYXXIiF9HNTtukFzrjlptdfsjgywkw);
    background-position: top;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.banner .navbar{
    margin-top:1%;
}
.banner .navbar-brand{
    color: #fff;
    font-size:1.8em;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
.banner .nav{
    margin-right:5%; 
}
.banner .nav li a{
    color:#aaa;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.banner .info{
    margin-top: 8%;
    transform: translateX(40%);
}

.banner .info p{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
  }

.banner .info a{
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #ff0081;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform ease-in 0.1s, box-shadow ease-in 0.25s;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 25px rgba(255, 0, 130, 0.5);
}

.banner .info a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.banner .info a:before, .banner .info a:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 140%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -20%;
  z-index: -1000;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.banner .info a:before {
  display: none;
  top: -75%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #ff0081 20%, transparent 20%), radial-gradient(circle, transparent 20%, #ff0081 20%, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle, #ff0081 20%, transparent 20%), radial-gradient(circle, #ff0081 20%, transparent 20%), radial-gradient(circle, transparent 10%, #ff0081 15%, transparent 20%), radial-gradient(circle, #ff0081 20%, transparent 20%), radial-gradient(circle, #ff0081 20%, transparent 20%), radial-gradient(circle, #ff0081 20%, transparent 20%), radial-gradient(circle, #ff0081 20%, transparent 20%);
  background-size: 10% 10%, 20% 20%, 15% 15%, 20% 20%, 18% 18%, 10% 10%, 15% 15%, 10% 10%, 18% 18%;
}
.banner .info a:after {
  display: none;
  bottom: -75%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #ff0081 20%, transparent 20%), radial-gradient(circle, #ff0081 20%, transparent 20%), radial-gradient(circle, transparent 10%, #ff0081 15%, transparent 20%), radial-gradient(circle, #ff0081 20%, transparent 20%), radial-gradient(circle, #ff0081 20%, transparent 20%), radial-gradient(circle, #ff0081 20%, transparent 20%), radial-gradient(circle, #ff0081 20%, transparent 20%);
  background-size: 15% 15%, 20% 20%, 18% 18%, 20% 20%, 15% 15%, 10% 10%, 20% 20%;
}
.banner .info a:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  background-color: #e60074;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 25px rgba(255, 0, 130, 0.2);
}
```

Comment: Какой вопрос то ?

Comment: Можно ли как-нибудь зафиксировать текст, чтобы он не перемещался при сжатии

Comment: Да, задать блоку **position: absolute;** или **position: fixed;**

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно в чем именно вопрос все-таки.
Если нужно чтобы текст не сжимался, то нужно исправить background-size

```
.banner{
    background-size:100% auto;
}
```

Если нужно чтобы картинки не было видно в адаптиве, разбивайте фон на 2: градиент и текст.  Тогда картинку с текстом можно будет зафиксировать.